# Can you define a function to change a C# property on the click of an hyperlink defined in c# code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I know that's impossible to do from an hyperlink defined in javascript, but I'm not sure if the ones defined on C# works the same way.

I mean I have this code:

```
HyperLink hlk;
...
hlk.NavigateUrl = url
```

I know I could define something like this:

```
hlk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return somefunction()");
```

But as far as I know something like that would only work for client-side code and I want it to change something from the server side.

Is there some way to do something like this with the things I'm mentioning? As the Hyperlink is generated from C# and not javascript there might be a way...

Comment: You could but it'd mean a page refresh.

Comment: Would you provide example for what you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an event Handler for the click event?

In C#, you need to do

```
Hyperlink hl;
// ... (setting of hyperlink)
hl.Click += HandlerFunction; // HandlerFunction is your method
```

And the parameter needed for a click event are `object sender, RoutedEventArgs e`

Answer (score 0):

Your server runs C# and communicates with a browser, right?
Anything that you create on the server-side will eventually be sent to the client's browser (html + javascript). it doesn't matter how was the hyperlink created (C#, Java, PHP) because it is converted to html and then sent away from the server.

You should use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to send commands to the server.

For example:

```
hlk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "doSomeAjax(url, command)");
```

And the `doSomeAjax` function on the client's side can look something like this (I used jQuery):

```
function doSomeAjax(url, command) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: command
    });
}
```

The url should point to an address you will make on the server that is designated to get commands. the command can be anything you want, for example `myVar=true`, then on your server side simply look for a myVar variable and change it to true.

This example is of course very vulnerable to many kinds of attacks!